# JSX syntax for exporting Array

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have this JSX component working properly:

```
import React from 'react'

const o = [1, 2]

export const ls = o.map((n, index) => 
  <li key={index}>{n}</li>
)
```

Trying to understand better JSX syntax, I have versioned it with no success, as the `export` results on unexpected token:

```
import React from 'react'

const o = [1, 2]

const ls = o.map((n, index) => 
    <li key={index}>{n}</li>
)

export ls
```

Is there any way of mapping the Array independently from the `export`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't export an object directly - you have to prefix it with the object type (const or function or default):

```
export default ls
// to import use:
import ls from './myfile.jsx'
```

or

```
export const ls = o.map(...)
// to import use:
import { ls } from './myfile.jsx'
```

or even

```
const ls = o.map(...)
export { ls }
// import with
import { ls } from './myfile.jsx'
```

Export Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export